# O que é e qual a utilidade da tabela DUAL para o Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Me deparei com este cenário durante a modificação de um relatório no sistema:

Uma das *querys* esta retornando para esta tal de tabela `DUAL`:

```
select * from dual
```

Porém no sistema não existe uma tabela DUAL, e a resposta que me deram foi que era uma tabela nativa do Oracle.

A partir disso surgiu as dúvidas:

- O que é e qual a utilidade da tabela DUAL?
- Se o objetivo é retornar um valor impossível, por que não retornar um valor que irá retornar `null` de uma tabela já existente?

Comment: Estou lendo, a utilidade ainda não entendi https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm, só entendi que é criada automaticamente e é acessivel a todos usuários, espero que o link ajude alguem a chegar proximo da resposta ;)

Comment: ela é uma tabela "imaginaria" para você utilizar funções, por exemplo você quer utilizar um sysdate(), você não pdoe simplesmente executa-lo tem que chamar no escopro de um select

Answer (score 21, accepted):

É uma espécie de tabela falsa com um único registro, usado para selecionar quando você não está realmente interessado nos dados, mas quer receber os resultado de alguma função ou variável.

Em palavras mais simples ela é uma tabela "*imaginária*" para você utilizar funções, por exemplo, você quer utilizar um *sysdate*, você não pode simplesmente executa-lo, você deve chamar no escopo de um *select*.

Exemplo:

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

[Fonte](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dual.html)

**EDIT**

Oracle difere do SQL Server em que você pode simplesmente selecionar sem ter uma cláusula *FROM*. Isso se deve principalmente pois a tabela dual permite que você possa criar um *JOIN*, ao contrario da maneira que o SQL Server trabalha. No Oracle é possível fazê-la duplicar as linhas, caso necessário. Além de que conceitualmente toda seleção deve possuir uma origem. A tabela dual é de origem genérica de um só registro, com a intenção de criar esta interação necessária entre os elementos.

[Fonte](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbadmin/mssqlserveradmin/what-is-the-dual-table/)

Answer (score 9):

Apenas complementando a resposta do Luiz Santos, dando exemplos comparativos com outros SGBDs:

No SQL Server ou MySQL, quando se deseja selecionar um valor que não está contido em uma tabela específica (como por exemplo uma variável declarada em um escopo de *query*, ou função nativa), podemos simplesmente usar o comando `SELECT`, sem especificar de onde selecionamos esses valores:

```
SELECT 'EXEMPLO'
```

Já nos bancos de dados Oracle, não conseguimos realizar o comando acima, tendo em vista a forma com que o Oracle trabalha as suas cláusulas de `SELECT`, obrigando-nos a explicitar de onde buscamos esses dados, por meio da cláusula `FROM`. Para o mesmo exemplo dado acima em um banco Oracle, a ação seria representada pela seguinte cláusula:

```
SELECT 'EXEMPLO' FROM DUAL
```

Na minha opinião é um conceito um tanto equisito (com cara de gambiarra) essa tabela "*imaginária*", usada para operações relativamente simples (uma seleção), que deixam o código até confuso para quem o lê ou vem de outro contexto que se aplica o SQL.

[Nesse link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Dual) há uma breve história da tabela, contada pelo seu criador, [Chuck Weiss](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Chuck_Weiss), caso te interesse, em inglês.

Comment: Na verdade, estranho deveria ser poder fazer ela seleção sem uma origem. No conceito de banco de dado toda seleção deve possuir uma origem. A dual é origem genérica de um só registro, com a intenção de criar esta interação necessária entre os elementos.

Comment: Além disso a dual permite que você possa criar um join, ao contrario da maneira que o sql serve trabalh. No oracle é possivel faze-la duplicas as linhas, caso necessário.

Comment: @LuizSantos Não acho. Por exemplo: se tenho uma query em que declaro uma variável dentro de seu escopo, e, desejo selecionar essa variável, por que tenho que falar que essa variável pertence à uma tabela (dual no caso)?

Comment: Não faz sentido colocar algo que não pertence à outro dentro dele. Pode-se levar em consideração até algebra relacional nesse caso (projete x mas x não está em dual, por que falar que está lá?)

Comment: Não é que ela pertença, mas é para você explicitar que quer apenasum registro deste, caso queira dois, poderá fazer join de dual. Não existem apenas casos em que você quer retornar apenas um registro igual o sql server permite, ainda mais no oracle um banco muito utilizado como "bando de regras"

Comment: Concordo que possam existir mais aplicações para a tabela, mas ainda assim na minha opinião, é um conceito bizarro do Oracle.

Comment: Acredito que seja algo de origem, eu nasci no oracle. Provavel que ja você não.

Comment: Sim, isto também influencia kkk, tenho costumes com o SQLServer

Comment: Sei que poucos são fãs de Matemática no sentido que nós, matemáticos, somos. Mas o que o Oracle faz me parece mais adequado do ponto de vista da álgebra relacional. Sobre o link em inglês, é legal ver que ela tem esse nome porque o que se queria originalmente eram duas linhas.