# Selecionar escalar em PL/SQL - Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Eu venho de um background de T-SQL (MS SQL Server) e tem coisas que não funcionam igual em PL/SQL.

Gostaria de saber como dar um select em escalares em PL/SQL.

Exemplos no MS SQL Server

Exemplo 1:

```
SELECT 1 + 1
```

Exemplo 2:

```
DECLARE @variavel INT = 1

SELECT @variavel
```

Como eu faria esses exemplos funcionarem em PL/SQL no Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é e qual a utilidade da tabela DUAL para o Oracle?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250279/o-que-%C3%A9-e-qual-a-utilidade-da-tabela-dual-para-o-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para os casos do exemplos acima, eu declaro uma variável usando `define`, `declare` não funciona.

Além disso, para conseguir trabalhar com a variável em um `select` eu devo adicionar `&&` à frente do nome da variável no momento da consulta:

```
define  
    a integer :=30
    select 'x' from dual where &&a = 31;
    select 'x' from dual where &&a = 30;
    select &&a from dual;
    select 1 + 1 from dual;
    select &&a + &&a from dual;
```